# Combinatorial inequality involving alternating signs

Tags: co.combinatorics, inequalities, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the following inequality. It arises from my study of random matrices.
I have verified the inequality for $q\in \{0.01,0.02, \ldots, 0.99\}$ and $1\le n\le 100$.

Let $n$ be any positive integer and $0\le q\le 1$. Then the following inequality is true.
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(q^k-q^n)^n\le (1-q^n)^n.$$

I suspect that the Wilf-Zeilberger method applies here. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Is this an inclusion-exclusion sum?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Yes, you are right. The post below by Fedor clarifies what the inclusion-exclusion sum is about. – shortfatboy

Comment: More generally, for integer $m,n\geq 0$ we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(q^k-q^n)^m\le (1-q^m)^n.$$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mark each box of an $n\times n$ table with probability $q$. By inclusion-exclusion the difference RHS-LHS equals to the probability that there exists a full row (with all boxes marked) but there does not exist a full column: that's because for given $k$ rows the probability that (they are full but no column is full) equals $(q^k-q^n)^n$.

Comment: Thanks, @FedorPetrov! You are right! Indeed, the LHS is equal to the probability that there does not exist a full row nor a full column, while the RHS is equal to the probability that there does not exist a full column. Clearly, LHS is at most RHS.

Comment: See also Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1 (2nd edition), Exercise 2.25(a).

Comment: And a previous MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125919/enumerating-0-1-finite-boxes-without-null-rays/

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica suggests that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{q^k-q^n}{1-q^n} \right)^n
 = 1-n q^n + n^2 O(q^{2n-1}) +  O(q^{2n})
$$
You can try to expandin $(q^k-q^n)^n$ using the binomial theorem,
and then try to change order of the sums.